# How to initialize thread local variables using async function

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to initialize thread local variables for all 4 threads at the beginning of the program.

```
thread_local! {
  static local: i32
}

#[tokio::main(worker_threads = 4)]
async fn main() {
   // local = get_local().await;
}
```

Comment: `async` tasks and thread-local storage don't usually play nicely together when you're using a multi-threaded executor (via `tokio::main`) where tasks can be moved between threads. What is the end goal here? Your thread-locals will already be initialized if you use the macro properly.

Comment: The end goal is to put some Tonic grpc client in thread_local so that I don't need to initialize the client every time. But I guess it's still possible to get a general solution? I have a fixed number of threads here, and my "real" program starts after initialization finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tokio runtime is configured to have 4 worker threads, your thread local is provided to the main thread but not to the worker threads.

If you intend to initialize the gRPC client just once, a `OnceCell` could be appropriate:

```
use once_cell::sync::OnceCell;

pub static CLIENT: OnceCell<hello_world::greeter_client::GreeterClient<tonic::transport::Channel>> =
    OnceCell::new();

pub fn client() -> hello_world::greeter_client::GreeterClient<tonic::transport::Channel> {
    CLIENT.get().unwrap().clone()
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let channel = tonic::transport::Endpoint::new("http://helloworld")
        .unwrap()
        .connect_lazy();
    let client = hello_world::greeter_client::GreeterClient::new(channel);
    CLIENT.set(client).unwrap();
    main_().await;
}

async fn main_() {
    let _ = client()
        .say_hello(hello_world::HelloRequest { name: "foo".into() })
        .await;
}

pub mod hello_world {
    tonic::include_proto!("helloworld");
}
```

If you want to stick to something more similar to a thread local or you need more control over the client values, then you can use tokio's task local.
It allows you to provide context to tasks, but keep in mind that `tokio::spawn` introduces new tasks, so this context is lost when you use `tokio::spawn`.

The following snippet makes a tonic client available through a `client()` helper function that internally calls `.with()` on the task local. This function panics if the task local is not set, there is also `try_with()` which returns a `Result` if the value is not provided.

```rust
use tokio::task_local;

task_local! {
    pub static CLIENT: hello_world::greeter_client::GreeterClient<tonic::transport::Channel>
}

pub fn client() -> hello_world::greeter_client::GreeterClient<tonic::transport::Channel> {
    CLIENT.with(|c| c.clone())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let channel = tonic::transport::Endpoint::new("http://helloworld")
        .unwrap()
        .connect_lazy();
    let client = hello_world::greeter_client::GreeterClient::new(channel);
    CLIENT.scope(client, main_()).await;
}

async fn main_() {
    let _ = client()
        .say_hello(hello_world::HelloRequest { name: "foo".into() })
        .await;
}

pub mod hello_world {
    tonic::include_proto!("helloworld");
}
```